# how to extract values from sql table

Tags: php, sql, database

```
> ID    ProductID   OptionName  OptionValue             SKU
> 
> 1           709      Title      Como  test
> 2           709     Color          Cobalt test
> 3           709     Color          Crimson            RNA.331.02.MM1K
> 4           709     Title          Como G2            RNA.331.02.MM1K
> 7           709     Color          another color      test ipn
> 8           709     Title          another title      test ipn
```

From the above table i want the following

```
Select distinct OptionName from myTable where ProductID = 709 group by OptionValue
```

but sql server is giving error on the group by clause and dont know how can i have all the different values grouped to distinct OptionName?

or i just can not ?

the result i want is as follows

```
[0] => array

    [Color] => array
        [0] => Cobalt test
        [1] => Crimson
        [2] => another color
   [Title] => array
       [0] => Como test
       [1] => Como G2
       [2] => another title
```

Comment: The SQL is semantically wrong, but I don't understand what you want. You select one column (without using a group function) but group on another. That is semantically incorrect. And it's group by (without underscore).

Comment: SQL cannot return nested arrays.  You'll have to transform the flat rowset on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an aggregate function on the fields (like FIRST(), LAST(), MAX(), AVG() ...) you are selecting when you have a GROUP BY-clause. Also, distinct is not necessary when you have GROUP BY. Can you explain what data you want to extract and not only post a faulty query?

**EDIT**:

```
SELECT OptionName, OptionValue FROM myTable WHERE ProductID = 709 ORDER BY OptionName ASC
```

Will produce this:

```
> OptionName    OptionValue             
> 
> Color          Cobalt test
> Color          Crimson                
> Color          another color   
> Title          Como   test    
> Title          Como G2
> Title          another title
```

Converting to arrays etc. is something you have to do in your application, not with SQL.

Comment: can you please help in sql syntax so that i can get all the optionvalue grouped under distinct optionnames thanks

Comment: I think you don't understand DISTINCT. If you add DISTINCT to the Query, it would output exactly the same given the sample data. If you want OptionName to only have distinct values, then you can only have ONE OptionValue per OptionName.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution

```
Select OptionName from myTable where ProductID = 709 limit 1
```

why does group by have an underscore

Comment: i have corrected the query please review the question again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the distinct and with the `OptionValue` in there

```
select OptionName
from myTable 
where ProductID = 709 
group by OptionName, OptionValue
```

Using the GROUP BY will give you the distinct combinations.

Answer (score 0):

By using `GROUP BY OptionValue` you're saying this...
- Get all the records from my query as normal
- Group records up that have the same OptionValue
- Return only one record for each of those groups

In your case, you then try to return the OptionName.  This is a problem because there are multiple OptionName's to display per group, but only one record to do so per group.

As has been said, the right Query depends on what you need, and I'm not 100% clear on that from what you have written.  (Giving an example of the results you need, and how to get those results, would help.)

My guess is that you just want two records (`Color` and `Title`).  If so you can do either of these...

`SELECT DISTINCT OptionName FROM myTable WHERE ProductID = 709`

`SELECT OptionName FROM myTable WHERE ProductID = 709 GROUP BY OptionName`

Comment: thanks for your answer i have updated my question can you please review it.